# App Store Connect says my 'Submit' button doesn't work for them on my React-Native Firebase project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, app-store-connect, mobile-development

I have a project I built in React-Native (and using firebase) that has been turned down twice by Apple's App Store Connect, because they say that the 'Submit' button doesn't do anything.

When they sent me a screenshot of the page where the error happens, I noticed their keyboard has an 'enter' key rather than 'send,' like you can see in the pictures.  I asked what OS they were using and they said IOS 17.2, which I am too.

[image: App Store Connect]

[image: My screenshot]

I have no idea what to try because it works perfectly for me, and the code is pretty simple. So, I figure I might just show you some of my code, and maybe someone will have run into a similar issue.

Here is the modal, where when the user clicks on the touchable opacity the function "modalGlobe" (improper naming, I know) is supposed to be triggered.  I think this is where the issue would be.

```
{/* GLOBAL Modal    GLOBAL Modal    GLOBAL Modal    GLOBAL Modal */}
<Modal
animationType='slide'
transparent={false}
visible={globeModalVis}
onRequestClose={()=>
console.log("whatevs globe")
}
>
<View style={globalStyles.modalCont}>
    <Image source={iEarth} style={globalStyles.modalImage} />
    <Text style={[globalStyles.basicText, globalStyles.white, {marginTop:'30%'}]}>{i18n.t('GlobalRoom')}</Text>
    <TextInput
    style={[globalStyles.usernameInput, {marginBottom: '5%'}]}
    placeholder={i18n.t('RoomPlaceholder')}
    value={custName}
    onChangeText={text=>setCustName(text)}
    returnKeyType="send"
    onSubmitEditing={modalGlobe}
    />
    <View style={globalStyles.modalButtons}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.modalBtn} onPress={()=>[setGlobeModalVis(false),setCustName('')]}>
            <Text style={[globalStyles.inputText, globalStyles.red]}>{i18n.t('Cancel')}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.modalBtn} onPress={modalGlobe}>
            <Text style={[globalStyles.inputText, globalStyles.green]}>{i18n.t('Submit')}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>    
</Modal>
```

Here is the function it's supposed to trigger:

```
const modalGlobe = () => {
    try {
        if(userName.length > 12 || userName.length < 3){
            showToast(i18n.t("ErrNameLength"))
            setGlobeModalVis(false)
            //test
            setNoNameDoor(2)
            setUsernameModalVis(true)
        }
        else if(custName.length > 13 || custName.length < 3){
            showToast(i18n.t("ErrRoomLength"))
        }
        else if(checkSuspension(suspendedDate))
        {
            showToast(i18n.t("SuspensionDate") + suspendedDate)
        }
        else if (latitude && longitude != null){          
            roomName = ""
            roomName = custName
            roomName = roomName.toLocaleLowerCase()        
            updateDateTime(userName)
            navigation.navigate("ChatRoom", {userName, roomName, rando, uniqueId})
            setGlobeModalVis(false)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in modalGlobe function:", error);
    }
}
```

When it gets to the "chatRoom" navigation, it should be loading up a mock conversation in the "Test" room I made for the App Store Connect team using this code.  (I doubt this has anything to do with, as the app doesn't seem to make it this far)

```
const colRef = firebase.firestore().collection( navigation.getParam("roomName") )
useEffect(() => { (async () => unmount())()
  const unsubscribe = colRef
    .orderBy('time', 'asc')
    .onSnapshot(
      querySnapshot => {
        const messages = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const { message, time, userName, col, Unique_ID } = doc.data()
          messages.unshift({
            id: doc.id,
            message,
            userName,
            time, 
            col,
            Unique_ID
          })
        })
        setMessages(messages)
      }
    )
    return () => {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}, [])
```

Again, it works for me.  It works on Android.  I've already got the app on the google play store, but App Store Connect is such a headache.  I honestly felt like they just made some dumb simple error, so I resubmitted it without even changing anything, but it still won't work for them.

Comment: Include code in your question as text in `code blocks`, not screenshots

Comment: I edited it to code blocks, thanks.